# Azure Table Storage: Capture all table activity for compliance purposes

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, auditing

I need to capture all inserts/updates/deletes in `Azure Table Storage` for compliance purposes. How is this accomplished? I'm looking for code samples and/or documentation. I know there is `Change Feed` support for blobs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-change-feed?tabs=azure-portal), which is still in preview. Anything similar for tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table storage does not provide any change feed or similar. If you need that, you could switch to "Premium Tables" which is basically Table API on Cosmos DB - which does provide things like change feed. Of course, this does come at a higher price point.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-introduction

Comment: I agree with the higher price point. Cosmos DB's pricing never made sense to me. I find it prohibitively expensive.

Comment: well, you asked for a solution ;-) and the costs of Cosmos obviously depend on your need, i.e. what kind of throughput you need

Answer (score 0):

If you're desperate you can try [Azure Storage analytics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging). Important caveat:

> Requests are logged on a best-effort basis. This means that most requests will result in a log record, but the completeness and timeliness of Storage Analytics logs are not guaranteed.

As such, it doesn't solve your compliance problem, but it might help someone else.